# VBScript to import images to word with filename as captions

Tags: image, import, vbscript, ms-word, caption

I'm importing a lot of result plots (png or jpg impages) into word, and need to automate this to speed up my work. I have managed to import the images but cannot figure out how to make a figure caption with the filename (or hardcodes as shown) as figure text.

```
'-------------CODE-----------------------------

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objShape = objDoc.Shapes

objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("C:\Plots\Plot1.PNG")
objShape.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", _  Title:=": Plot1", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
  objSelection.insertbreak

objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("C:\Plots\Plot2.PNG")
objShape.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", _  Title:=": Plot2", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
  objSelection.insertbreak

objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("C:\Plots\Plot3.PNG")
objShape.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", _  Title:=": Plot3", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
  objSelection.insertbreak

objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("C:\Plots\Plot4.PNG")
objShape.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", _  Title:=": Plot4", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
  objSelection.insertbreak

'----------END-OF-CODE-----------------------
```

Comment: You'll have to give more details then simply saying it doesn't work. What is happening exactly, what are the errors if any, ... I'm guessing you are getting a bunch of syntax errors because of the named parameters, and the underscores without a newline?

Comment: I managed to get the caption working, see my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed at last to make a script that loops through all PNG-files and import them with caption and line spaces between, and finally save this to a new word file.

```
' Script to read PNG files into a word document
' the PNG files and script need to be in the same folder

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

' Folder to process
strFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Access the folder to process
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    ' Only import PNG files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = LCase("PNG") Then

       objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (objFile.Path)
       objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf)   
       objselection.InsertCaption "Figure", vbTab & objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile) , "", wdCaptionPositionBelow
       objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf)   
       objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf)   

    Else
    '  Wscript.Echo "No PNG files in """ & objFile.Path & """"
    End If

Next

DOCXFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(objFolder, "Plots.docx")
objDoc.SaveAs(DOCXFilePath)
objWord.Quit
```